How to retrieve value in controller of properties with [JsonPropertyName] applied?
public class PropertyCollection
{
    [JsonPropertyName("User Name:")]
    public string UserName { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    [JsonPropertyName("User Password:")]
    public string UserPassword { get; set; } = string.Empty;
}

[HttpPost("usersubmit", Name = "user-data")]
[ServiceFilter(typeof(ValidateMediaTypeAttribute))]
public IActionResult PostUserData([FromBody] PropertyCollection UserCol, string userId)
{
    return new OkObjectResult(iUserDataHelper.PostUserData(UserCol, userId));
}   

I am getting null value for UserName and UserPassword.
This API project was developed using .NET 8.0.
Please help!
Expected result: the correct value

Can you include the payload you're sending in the question?

Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], specifically the raw request you are sending (especially the JSON body).  It might also help to share the calls to .AddJsonOptions(options =>{}) you make during startup, since System.Text.Json is case-sensitive by default.  Finally, please tag your question with the frameworks and versions you are using, e.g. is it [tag:asp.net-core]?  [tag:minimal-apis]?  Thanks!
